# jquery knockout inside google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, knockout.js

I have a google map, and a custom control which contains a jquery knockout binding:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.cities = ko.observableArray();
};
var viewModel = new ViewModel();

// ajax call which populates cities array

var googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var controlHtml = $("<ul data-bind='foreach: cities'></ul>");
googleMap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlHtml[0]);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The list is added on the map, but the knockout bindings doesn't work. If i add the same list on `body` tag, the list is binded.

Is possible to use jquery knockout inside google maps custom controls?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a timeout fixes the problem:

```
var controlHtml = $("<ul data-bind='foreach: cities'><li data-bind='text: Name'></li></ul>");
googleMap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlHtml[0]);

setTimeout(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}, 1000);
```